# How to publish message on facebook wall

Tags: java, facebook

How can I publish a message on facebook wall using `java`?

Comment: just in case this hasn't been asked before http://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 5):

It looks pretty involved.  There's a detailed explanation on how to use the [facebook-java-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/) to do this in the article [Facebook Java api example to publish on Wall](http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/facebook-java-api-example-to-publish-on-wall/).